# How can I get a reference to Android Context during deserialization?

Tags: java, android, serialization

I have a class that holds a reference to a Context, and I plan to serialize an object of this class. As you know, a `Context` object cannot be serialized, so I've marked it as `transient`.

Now, the problem I'm facing is how can I restore the state of the `Context` reference? I need to somehow pass in a reference to the application's current context during deserialization. Is there a way to do this during deserialization, or do I have to first restore the object and then reinitialize the `transient` variable through a seperate method or something.

Comment: What are you trying to serialize that requires Context to restore?

Comment: It's an object of a class that I've declared, which holds a reference to a system service, such as NotificationManager, WifiManager, Audiomanager, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at overriding readObject() method. And in readObject(), you can initialize Context variable to whatever value you consider suitable.

e.g

```
class Test implements Serializable{
 private int a;
 private string b;
 transient Context c;
 private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException{
  in.defaultReadObject();
  //now initialize transient fields
  c=ContextFactory.getContext();
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the Context I'm speaking of is android.content.Context and can't be retrieved through a static method.

Comment: @WindsurferOak my point is that in readResolve method, you can initialize context to a suitable value.

Comment: I understand your point. After re-reading my question, I can see I wasn't clear. More than overriding readObject/writeObject, I'm looking for a way to get a handle to the Context. One way, as you suggested is through a static method, which is ultimately how it needs to be done, but how to do this specifically?